# I am working on background color change using Button in Android studio

Tags: android, random, onclicklistener, background-color, setbackground

```
LinearLayout abc = findViewById(R.id.view);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int max = 1;
                int min = 225;
                Random rand = new Random();
                int a = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                int b = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                int c = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                int d = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                abc.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a, b, c, d));
            }

        }));
```

I tried with Switch too but my app is closed or return to previous Activity.

Comment: Can you please add code and crash logs ?

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout abc = findViewById(R.id.view);
        //abc.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 56, 170, 255));
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 255);
                int b = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 255);
                int c = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 255);
                int d = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 255);
                abc.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a,b,c,d));

            }

        }));
```

You were also so much help full Anil Thankyou for answering.
Here is my [twitter](https://twitter.com/parag_jawle/status/1506919867923927043) account I just started yesterday uploading
Maybe it will be helpful in future.

Answer (score -1):

**Change Background Color of a Layout**

If your requirement is changing Background color of a layout Dynamically means, Try any of the below

**If you are outside an activity**

```
abc.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

**If you are on activity**

```
abc.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

**If you want to set color from Android Graphics color**

```
abc.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

**If you want to set color from using Hexa Code**

```
abc.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

**OR If you want to set color randomly**

```
fun Int.Companion.randomColor(): Int{
{
 return Color.argb(255,
 Random.nextInt(256),
 Random.nextInt(256),
 Random.nextInt(256))
}
```

*and this is the usage:`abc.setBackgroundColor(Int.randomColor());`*

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all, look at what OP is trying to achieve

Comment: I have edited the answer now.

Comment: but OP is looking to set a value based on a random color, so i'm not sure how this answers it

Comment: Ok Answered it now

Comment: you're trying to answer this question way too quickly and without a reference to what OP is asking, again, what's the point of using kotlin code when OP is asking in java ?

Comment: I tried yesterday and finally its done

Comment: I set Linear layout to fill color I do not know how to do it without linear layout. If you know plz Answer it

Comment: Please share your xml code and tell exactly about your requirement @ParagJawle